# Is it possible to check git commits to include specific character?

Tags: git

Git lovers

I have to include "#+story number" in my git commits but sometimes I forget to mention it.
I'm looking for a way to prevent my wrong commits!.
I have fount [this document](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy) and as it said modified the .git/hooks/commit-msg.sample file with this content(just for test):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
message_file = ARGV[0]
message = File.read(message_file)

$regex = /\[ref: (\d+)\]/

if !$regex.match(message)
  puts "[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly"
  exit 1
end
```

but it didn't work!
do you have any experience or idea about this?
Best regards

Comment: What do you mean saying "doesn't work"? Also please note: the linked document doesn't mention `commit-msg.sample`, it mentions `commit-msg`.

Comment: "doesn't work" means as the document said if I try
$ git commit -am 'test'
it should give me this:
[POLICY] Your message is not formatted correctly
but instead of that Git allows me to commit
and when i read the document more carefully it looks i have to make this script excitable! Do you have any idea how to make it ?

Comment: Your commit hook also need execute permission.